# Multiple instances of the same AdSense ad unit (same data-ad-slot) on a page?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Each ad unit has a unique `data-ad-slot`, right?

[image]

Can I have multiple instances of the same ad unit (i.e: the same ad-slot) running on the same page? Could this be a bad practice, somehow?

For example:

I have an ad unit called `Landing_FIXED` which I place twice on my homepage.

And I have `MainPost_FIXED` which I place 2, 3 or 4 times in my blog posts.

Is this fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine, you can add it multiple times on the page without problems.

What you'll lose is visibility, in that you won't know the stats of how good or bad an ad performed on position 1 vs position 2. You can use channels of course, but I prefer to use different ad-slots and channels for measurement.